# Fetch data from date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, date, range, date-range

I want to see my `room_requests` which have duration included in my date range from form. Here's what I've done:

controller for this view:

```
def not_confirmed_slots
  if params[:search] 
    @slots = RoomRequest.find(:all, :conditions => ['date >= ? and date =< ?', params[:start_date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), params[:end_date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]) 
        if @projects.size.zero? 
          flash[:notice] = "No result found" 
          @slots = RoomRequest.find(:all) 
        end 
  else 
    @slots = RoomRequest.all
  end
end
```

and my form from view:

```
%h1= t('headers.reports.notConfirmedSlots')
  = form_tag not_confirmed_slots_reports_path, method: 'get' do
    %p
      = text_field_tag :start_date, nil,  :class => "datepicker", :placeholder => t('placeholders.reports.startDate')
    %p
      = text_field_tag :end_date, nil, :class=>"datepicker", :placeholder => t('placeholders.reports.endDate')
    .clear
       .action_bar
          = submit_tag t('buttons.reports.generate'), {class: "button blue"}
```

But every time I submit form with dates it lists me all room_requests from db - any tips?

Oh, and here is the partial (it's on the same view where is search form):

```
%table
  - @slots.each do |s|
    %tr
      %td
        = s.bookers_name
      %td
        = s.request_type
```